# Whenever cron job is not working in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, whenever, cron-task

This is the code in my schedule file. I am using 1 min just to test whether its working or not.

```
every 1.minutes do
  runner "User.update_all('daily_sms_count' = 0 )"
end
```

from terminal i setup

```
whenever --set environment=development --update-crontab 1mintesting
```

Whats the issue?

Comment: i think whenever does not run properly in development mode. I had also problems with that. did you try to start you server in production and see if it works?

Comment: @frank yaa.. u are right.. its not working on development mode.. worked perfectly fine in server.. thanks bro..

Answer (score 6):

Are you using RVM? If so, Whenever generates a crontab entry like this:

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 
'cd /Users/myuser/Documents/Projects/foo && script/rails runner -e 
development '\''User.update_all("daily_sms_count" = 0 )'\'''
```

This means that it won't necessarily be using your project's version of Ruby and associated gemset as it spins off a new bash shell. To make this work, you need to add an appropriate `.rvmrc` file to your project's root folder. This way, the `cd /Users/myuser/Documents/Projects/foo` part of the generated crontab entry will ensure that the appropriate RVM settings are used. Just make sure that when you add the `.rvmrc` file, `cd..` and back into the project to make RVM recognize your project's `.rvmrc`.

If you are not using RVM, run `crontab -l`, and copy the generated entry, and run it from terminal to see if it runs with no errors or not.

If you are using Mac, `cron` will send log messages to your mailbox and you can view them using the `mail` command.

If these tricks didn't work, give me more details about your working environment (OS, RVM, etc.) so that I can help you more.

Comment: the `mail` command works for me on a mac. I'm only not seeing the messages appear every 10,20 minutes/hours/days. Why is that?